# Patching with Wix for major upgrades

Tags: wix, windows-installer, patch

I am trying to support patches with Wix and was looking for answer like [on this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359052/generating-patches-with-wix-base-version-3-off-version-1-or-version-2)

As suggested I used the "Using Purely WiX" code to do some testing and created 3 versions 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2

I can apply each of the MSI correctly to upgrade without errors and in ARP the version gets incremented.

I can patch from 1.0 or 1.1 to 1.2 but in ARP the version is not updated. As well after patching to 1.2 and running the 1.1 MSI installer, I then don't get the warning about downgrading.

Where am I going wrong here.

Here's the source:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
    <Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
    <Product Id='*' Name='Foobar $(var.Version)' UpgradeCode='PUT-GUID-HERE'
        Language='1033' Codepage='1252' Version='$(var.Version).0.0' Manufacturer='Acme Ltd.'>

        <Package Id='*' Keywords='Installer' Description="Acme's Foobar $(var.Version) Installer"
            Comments='Foobar is a registered trademark of Acme Ltd.' Manufacturer='Acme Ltd.'
            InstallerVersion='100' Languages='1033' Compressed='yes' SummaryCodepage='1252' />
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage='A newer version is already installed.' />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab='yes' />
        <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
            <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
                <Directory Id='Acme' Name='Acme'>
                    <Directory Id='INSTALLDIR' Name='Foobar'>
                        <Component Id='MainExecutable' Guid='*'>
                            <File Id='SampleTXT' Name='Sample.txt' DiskId='1' Source='ver$(var.Version)\Sample.txt' KeyPath='yes' />
                        </Component>
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
        <Feature Id='Complete' Level='1'>
            <ComponentRef Id='MainExecutable' />
        </Feature>
    </Product>
</Wix>

    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
    <Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
    <Patch AllowRemoval="yes" Manufacturer="Acme Ltd." MoreInfoURL="www.acmefoobar.com"
        DisplayName="Foobar 1.1.0 Patch" Description="Small Update Patch" Classification="Update">

        <Media Id='5000' Cabinet='Sample.cab'>
            <PatchBaseline Id='Sample'/>
        </Media>

        <PatchFamily Id='SamplePatchFamily' Version='1.1.0.0' Supersede='yes'>
            <ComponentRef Id='MainExecutable'/>
        </PatchFamily>

    </Patch>
</Wix>
```

and built with:

```
"%WIX_COMP_CMD%" -nologo -dVersion=1.0 Product.wxs
"%WIX_LINK_CMD%" -nologo Product.wixobj -out ver1.0\Product.msi

"%WIX_COMP_CMD%" -nologo -dVersion=1.1 Product.wxs
"%WIX_LINK_CMD%" -nologo Product.wixobj -out ver1.1\Product.msi

"%WIX_COMP_CMD%" -nologo -dVersion=1.2 Product.wxs
"%WIX_LINK_CMD%" -nologo Product.wixobj -out ver1.2\Product.msi

"%WIX_TORCH_CMD%" -nologo -p -xi ver1.0\Product.wixpdb ver1.2\Product.wixpdb -out Patch_0_2.wixmst
"%WIX_TORCH_CMD%" -nologo -p -xi ver1.1\Product.wixpdb ver1.2\Product.wixpdb -out Patch_1_2.wixmst

"%WIX_COMP_CMD%" -nologo Patch.wxs
"%WIX_LINK_CMD%" -nologo Patch.wixobj

"%WIX_PYRO_CMD%" -nologo Patch.wixmsp -out Patch.msp -t Sample Patch_0_2.wixmst -t Sample Patch_1_2.wixmst
```